# translate jade/pug to html to retrieve data from mongoDB database

Tags: javascript, html, mongodb, pug, mean

I'm having trouble translating:

```
ul
   each comment, i in comments
       li= comment.title
```

from jade/pug to html.

comments is a collection of a mongoDB database. I'm trying to retrieve the data from the comments collection and display it. I'm using NodeJS, ExpressJS, and MongoDB. I've tried some javascript code to loop through comments but didn't work.

Comment: Can you share your the endpoint where you get/post those `comments`? i.e. Node Js code snippet.

Comment: `app.get('/', function(req, res){Comment.find({}, function(err, comments){
  if(err){
   console.log(err);
  } else {
   res.render('index', {
    title:'Comments',
    comments:comments
   });
  }
 });
});`

Comment: Can you try `console.log( comments )` somewhere in the endpoint before `res.render( ... )` ?

Comment: I get the comments in json format in the terminal when i do that

Comment: can you try editing to `each comment in comments`?

Comment: that gives the same result when using pug(displays the contents of the collection). What I'm trying to do is to use html instead of pug because I want to add this functionality to another project where I'm already using html

Comment: Oh, then you can use [EJS](https://github.com/tj/ejs) in that case. For converting from Pug to HTML, use [this](https://www.browserling.com/tools/jade-to-html).